# REST-сервис с помощью FastApi

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, datetime, fastapi

Не могу понять, что именно мешает авторизоваться. Окно авторизации вылезает, но вне зависимости от правильности введенных данных, выдает ошибку "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 401 Unauthorized
Вроде токен выделяется.... Подскажите, кто увидел ошибку.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from jose import jwt
from passlib.context import CryptContext
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasicCredentials

app = FastAPI()
pwd_context = CryptContext(schemes=["bcrypt"], deprecated="auto")
secret_key = "your-secret-key"
access_token_expire_minutes = 30


users = {
    "admin": {
        "username": "admin",
        "password": pwd_context.hash("admin123"),
        "salary": 5000,
        "last_promotion": "2023-01-01"
    },
    "user1": {
        "username": "user1",
        "password": pwd_context.hash("user123"),
        "salary": 3000,
        "last_promotion": "2022-06-01"
    }
}

def verify_password(username, password):
    if username in users and pwd_context.verify(password, users[username]["password"]):
        return True
    return False

def create_access_token(username):
    expires = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=access_token_expire_minutes)
    payload = {"username": username, "expires": expires}
    return jwt.encode(payload, secret_key, algorithm="HS256")

@app.post("/token")
def login(username: str, password: str):
    if not verify_password(username, password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid username or password")
    
    access_token = create_access_token(username)
    return {"access_token": access_token, "token_type": "bearer"}

def get_current_salary(username):
    return users[username]["salary"]

def get_next_promotion(username):
    last_promotion = datetime.strptime(users[username]["last_promotion"], "%Y-%m-%d")
    next_promotion = last_promotion + timedelta(days=365)
    return next_promotion.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

def authenticate(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends()):
    if not verify_password(credentials.username, credentials.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid username or password")
    
    return credentials.username

@app.get("/salary")
def get_salary(username: str = Depends(authenticate)):
    salary = get_current_salary(username)
    next_promotion = get_next_promotion(username)
    return {"salary": salary, "next_promotion": next_promotion}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def verify_password(username, password):
    if username in users:
       if pwd_context.verify(password, users[username]["password"]):
          return True
       return False
    return False
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это по логике ничем не отличается от того что в коде вопроса, просто вы одно условие разбили на два

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь использовать [HTTP-Basic-auth](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/http-basic-auth/)

```
def authenticate(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends()):
    if not verify_password(credentials.username, credentials.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Invalid username or password")
    
    return credentials.username
```

вместе с [OAuth2 scopes](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/security/oauth2-scopes/).

```
def create_access_token(username):
    expires = datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(minutes=access_token_expire_minutes)
    payload = {"username": username, "expires": expires}
    return jwt.encode(payload, secret_key, algorithm="HS256")
```

Скорее всего ошибка кроется в этом, советую выбрать что-то одно.
Также согласно документации вам стоит добавить

```
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic
```

и исправить.

```
def authenticate(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
```